# I am using action_send for Facebook sharing here insert image only but not added text what is the reason?

Tags: facebook

Here is Facebook sharing code:

```
String text = "Offer Ends:" + offerending + "\n Offer Type:"
                    + offertype + "\n Address:" + offaddress + "\n"
                    + webbsuitee;

            String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/" + "temporary_file.jpg";

            File file = new File(completePath);
//              Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
             Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
             shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             shareIntent.setType("image/*");
             shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
             shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

             shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is closed by Facebook API. You need to use the Facebook SDK for Android to do so!
check this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423